# Modifying Worker.navigator and Other Attributes in Selenium to Simulate Different OS

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with Python and attempting to trick the browser (chrome) into thinking I'm on a Windows machine when I'm actually running Linux.

So far, I have managed to modify the User-Agent to mimic a Windows system:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

I have also used the following line to change navigator.platform:
`driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': "Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'platform', {get: () =\> 'Win32'})"})`

However, these modifications appear to be insufficient. I've learned that the browser can also detect the platform through WorkerNavigator.platform, but I'm unsure of how to modify this.

Are there other attributes that I should consider changing to successfully emulate a Windows environment in the browser using Selenium? Any insights or guidance would be much appreciated.